# C#, XML - Loading a single XML file into two separate datasets based on a parameter

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dataset, xmldocument

I need to load XML data into two separate datasets based on a given parameter within the XML. The data is fed back to me via a SOAP call.

Here is a very simplified XML sample:

```
<![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>

<ArrayOfUser xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<User>
    <ID>111-111-111</ID
    <Name>John Smith</Name>
    <Active>0</Active>
</User>

<User>
    <ID>111-111-222</ID
    <Name>Bob Smith</Name>
    <Active>0</Active>
</User>

<User>
    <ID>111-111-333</ID
    <Name>Sally Smith</Name>
    <Active>1</Active>
</User>


</ArrayOfUser>]]>
```

Right now, I load everything into a single dataset as such:

```
XmlDocument UsersXmlDoc= new XmlDocument();
UsersXmlDoc.LoadXml(GetUsersResponse.Fetch_Result);
XmlReader UsersXmlReader= new XmlNodeReader(UsersXmlDoc);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(UsersXmlReader);
```

I would like instead to split that information into two datasets based on the **Active** property of each user so that one dataset contains active uses and the other, innactive users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an example how you could do what you want. Maybe code isn't very nice, but I think it should work. The main idea is to copy current dataset and remove active records from first and inactive records from second dataset.

```
DataSet dsActive = new DataSet();
dsActive.ReadXml(UsersXmlReader);

DataSet dsInactive = ds.Copy();//Copy to your another dataset
Remove(dsActive.Tables[0], "0");//Remove all inactive(where Active = 0) records from dsActive DataSet
Remove(dsInactive.Tables[0], "1");//Remove all active(where Active = 1) records from dsInactive DataSet

private void Remove(DataTable table, string active)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (table.Rows[i]["Active"].Equals(active))
        {
            table.Rows[i].Delete();
            i = i - 1;//Removed record so we need to check same index
        }
    }
}
```